# Setting a scrollbar position

Tags: javascript, scrollbar

I have a table inside of a div (it's overflow, so the browser renders a scrollbar). Using JavaScript, how do I move the scrollbar handle along the track to a position that corresponds to the location of a row in the table?

```
+--------------------------------------+
|100                               |   |
|101                               |   |
|102                               |   |
|103                               |   |
|104                               |   |
|105     This is a table that      |---|
|106        has overflowed.        | - |  <-- I want to move this using JavaScript,
|107                               |---|      so that a specific row # is visible.
|108                               |   |
|109                               |   |
|110                               |   |
|111                               |   |
+--------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 55):

If you want to go the non-[jQuery way](https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/), use the containing table's [`scrollTop` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop).

Lets assume you can easily identify the row you want to scroll to using an ID, along with the containing `<div />`. Use the [`offsetTop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetTop) of the element you want to scroll to.

```
var container = document.getElementById('myContainingDiv');
var rowToScrollTo = document.getElementById('myRow');

container.scrollTop = rowToScrollTo.offsetTop;
```

Comment: basically the link # method is pretty useless if you have a fixed header, as it will overlap the top of the scrolled location

Comment: scrollTop is not supported by IE and Edge. See https://caniuse.com/#search=scrolltop

Comment: @yuxiaomin That link doesn't show support for scrollTop. It shows support for `scrollBy` and `scrollTo`. See the MDN article on scrollTop (included in my answer) which includes a support table that shows it is indeed supported by IE and Edge browsers.

Comment: @DanHerbert Oh, yes. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
$('a').on('click', function(e){
  var t = this.id.substring(1);
  e.preventDefault();
  var target= $(".section")[t] ;
  var offset = $( target ).offset();
  $('html, body').stop().animate({
    scrollTop: offset.top
  }, 1000);
});
```

Also, you could check this [example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hessamnadr/ys4b6j0n/) .

Answer (score 1):

**Using Jquery:**

'.scroll-table' is the class name used for scroll-able part

1.First go to the initial position

```
$('.scroll-table').scrollTop(0);
```

2.Below line calculates the scroll difference between the tables top position and the row to which we have scroll

```
$('.scroll-table').scrollTop($('#myrowid').position().top-$('.scroll-table').position().top);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in jQuery here, you can do it as follows:

```
$(".tableClass tbody").scrollTop(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `.scrollTop()` jQuery method:

https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution using AngularJs.

```
  $document.scrollTopAnimated(50, 1000).then(function () {});
```

The first parameter is the position. The second is the duration of animation.