# Scroll large image on menu click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a rather large image (not my choice how it was given to me) I have a simple navigation structure and when I click on one of the links I want to be able to scroll to a certain point of the large jpg below the menu. It's one large image so using # isn't going to work. I assume this is going to need to be a javascript or jquery function, but I'm just how sure how to set that up. I've looked around but everything I found is for a slide show, where I just have one overly large image that I need to scroll down and up via a menu button. I tried having the a tag jump around the page, and that kind of worked, but it didn't scroll it just jumped.

I wish I had code to show, but nothing I have used worked.

Comment: How about using [JavaScript to change the position of the scroll bar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3562202/setting-a-scrollbar-position)

Comment: @icekomo So you want to scroll at certain part of content(text/element) on menu click?

Comment: yeah I have a menu with a few links in it, and I want those links to scroll a large image below them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `scrollTop` property of `element` like `body` or any `div` to scroll at any position. [see here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KdgPRx) created a pen for the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to animate the page scroll you will probably need to use jQuery's animate function.

```
$("html, body").animate({ 
    scrollTop: 400 /*Desired offset position*/ 
}, 1000);
```

Take a look at this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ktxp87tz/) as an example.

You could also position anchors behind the image at the positions you need the page to scroll

See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ktxp87tz/1/)

Comment: Thanks Jackson, I didn't even think of putting anchors behind the image.. really interesting idea....