# How to move table scrollbar using js, jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table as follows with a horizontal scrollbar.

```
 <table >
    <tr>
        <th>Col1</th>
        <th>col2</th>
        <th>col3</th>
        <th>col4</th>
        <th>col5</th>
        <th>col5</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[image]
Is there a way to move the scrollbar using javascript(dynamicaly). For example I want to move scrollbar 30px right when clicking a button.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3562516/492258

Comment: Please look at my edited answer below..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

click on right to scroll to right, and on left to scroll back.. this is an idea how it could work. Cheers.

```js
$(".leftArrow").click(function () { 
  var leftPos = $('.wrapper').scrollLeft();
  $(".wrapper").animate({scrollLeft: leftPos - 30}, 100);
});

$(".rightArrow").click(function () { 
  var leftPos = $('.wrapper').scrollLeft();
  $(".wrapper").animate({scrollLeft: leftPos + 30}, 100);
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  width:100px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

table {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Col1</th>
      <th>col2</th>
      <th>col3</th>
      <th>col4</th>
      <th>col5</th>
      <th>col5</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<button class="leftArrow">Scroll left</button>

<button class="rightArrow">Scroll right</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the element.scrollLeft = 30px method in javascript. So for example if your table's ID is "table", you could say :

```
table = document.getElementById("table")
function scroll_right(){
    table.scrollLeft = 30px
}
```

And then if you want to have a button in html that scrolls to the right :

```
<button onclick="scroll_right">Scroll right</button>
```

Comment: this method is used to scroll the window, isn't it? I only need to scroll the table

Comment: Well in that case you can use element.scrollLeft = 30px, I changed the answer above to give you an example